# is running 2 separate networks off one modem possible?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

My cable company just replaced my modem (15 yrs old) with a new modem and router in one device. We have also connected our old router (actually a brand new replacement (wifi6) router to the new modem/router. we are now running into problems. devices that have not ben configured for the new router still see the old network and connect to the internet fine. The several devices we converted to the new network work ok on it but when we tried to switch them back to the old we are getting a msg asking us to reset the old router - we do not want to do this if at all possible. Is there a work around for these devices so that they can see and connect to either network as we want?

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-to-connect-and-have-two-separate-networks-with-1-modem-and-2-routers.1472279/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do what you are trying to do.

Get a good Router that supports VLANs .

Putt the ISP Modem into Bridge mode (you will need the ISP to do this for you).

Hook up the Router, get an External IP and ensure the router has Internet.

Now set up the two VLANs to service your two networks.

I am using the clarity of your question line to answer this.